# getting Arial Label value from list of buttons

Tags: javascript

So we have various buttons which looks like this

```js
  var val =  document.querySelectorAll('button[aria-label]')[0].value;
  console.log(val);
```

```html
<button aria-label="Connect with Trijay Sharda" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6704="6704" data-is-animating-click="true">Connect</button>

<button aria-label="Connect with Vibhor Jain" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-7497="7497">Connect</button>
```

But this just returns an empty string.

**[Question]** So I have two questions, Why does it returns empty string and how can I grab the value of aria-label here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('button[aria-label]')[0]` is giving you the button element.

So you're seeing the `.value` of the button element. If you want to see `Connect` then you can access the `.innerText`.

`.getAttribute('aria-label')` will give you the value of your aria label.

```js
  var button =  document.querySelectorAll('button[aria-label]')[0];
  console.log(button.getAttribute('aria-label')); // Connect with Trijay Sharda
  console.log(button.innerText); // Connect
```

```html
<button aria-label="Connect with Trijay Sharda" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-6704="6704" data-is-animating-click="true">Connect</button>

<button aria-label="Connect with Vibhor Jain" data-control-name="srp_profile_actions" class="search-result__actions--primary button-secondary-medium m5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-7497="7497">Connect</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the answer But still button element have a value **connect** (connect is between opening and closing tabs of button)

Comment: Actually it does not have the `.value` of *Connect*. That can be accessed through `.innerText` or `.innerHTML`.

Comment: The main difference here is that this button has that text within the element, moreso as a child of the element. Inputs tend to have their values as an attribute on the element, that's why those are accessible via `.value`.